# How to retrieve these elements from a webpage?

Tags: python

I have a webpage in HTML with these elements:

```
<div class="content_page">
    <a href="/earth" class="nametessera" >earth</a>
</div>
<div class="content_page">
    <a href="/world" class="nametessera" >world</a>
</div>
<div class="content_page">
    <a href="/planet" class="nametessera">planet</a>
</div>
...
```

I need to retrieve /earth, /world, /planet, etc.
so I need to retrieve all links of tag A with class "nametessera".

How can I do this with python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

Use [**beautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) to parse the page, get the urls and then use [**urlib2**](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or [**pycurl**](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/pycurl.html) to download the mentioned urls.

[Edit:]

Adding on to the examples below but to only use the the href contained in the div

```
>>> alldiv = soup.findAll('div', { "class" : "content_page" })
>>> for div in alldiv: print div.a
... 
<a href="/earth" class="nametessera">earth</a>
<a href="/world" class="nametessera">world</a>
<a href="/planet" class="nametessera">planet</a>
>>> for div in alldiv: print div.a['href']
... 
/earth
/world
/plan
```

Similarly you could also do

```
allHref = soup.findAll('a', { "class" : "nametessera" })
```

Comment: Actually soup.findAll('div', { "class" : "content_page" }) is equivalent of soup.findAll("div", "content_page")

Comment: @zifot: Yes. Thanks. My habit of passing that as dict makes it cumbersome. :)

Answer (score 3):

You parse the HTML with [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

The documentation is [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).