# How to retrieve onclick text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a webpage I have these elements:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('/link.php?webpage=45980a6f91ac0c850745e0500d612172" class="pagelink" >Page 1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('/link.php?webpage=45980a6f91ac0c850745e05676787895" class="pagelink" >Page 2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('/link.php?webpage=45980a6f91ac0c85786787666456fgg3" class="pagelink" >Page 3</a>
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('/link.php?webpage=45980a6f91ac0c850734234324756767" class="pagelink" >Page 4</a>
...
```

.

and I need to retrieve the text in the window.open function of all A tags of class "pagelink":

```
/link.php?webpage=45980a6f91ac0c850745e0500d612172
/link.php?webpage=45980a6f91ac0c850745e05676787895
/link.php?webpage=45980a6f91ac0c85786787666456fgg3
/link.php?webpage=45980a6f91ac0c850734234324756767
```

How can I do this with python ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve these elements from a webpage ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328167/how-to-retrieve-these-elements-from-a-webpage)

Comment: You're calling a PHP script from your `onClick`; that may be it difficult to, you know, read from Python...

Comment: @chrisaycock: yeah, that confused me too, until I realized he's parsing *source* script, not a running page. A little clarification in the question would have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attr = dict(attrs)
        if attrs["class"] == "pagelink":
            add_to_result(attrs["onclick"])
```

Replace `add_to_result` with your aggregation object (e.g. list) and actual code, and then just remove leading `window.open` from results.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328167/how-to-retrieve-these-elements-from-a-webpage). You need to parse HTML to get *any* data that you might require from it. The parsing is done with Beautiful Soup.

Of course someone might post the code as it is, but that is no fun right?

So again, you have to read up the documentation :)